# How to configure DataTables to work with Page Number instead of Start record

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have an existing web application that currently uses jqGrid and the entire server-side backend returns paginated info based on Page Number and Page Length. 
Now I want to start using DataTables on some parts, and since its pagination uses Start record and Length, I want to know if there's some way to configure DataTables to accept Page Number so I don't have to modify my whole backend.

Any way to configure or maybe adapt DataTables for this?

Edit: just to avoid confusion, I'm talking about DataTables with the server-side processing functionality, not about the client-side pagination.

EDIT 2: Adding some code of how my backend takes and responds to the requests from the browser. It's ASP.NET MVC4.

My Services respond always with pages of data of the entity being worked with with a method like this:

```
Page<T> GetPage<TKey>(int pageNumber,
                      int pageSize,
                      Expression<Func<T, TKey>> orderBy,
                      bool ascending = true,
                      Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null)
```

This will return a `Page<T>` object like this:

```
public class Page<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly IList<T> _items;

    public IList<T> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }

    public Page()
    {}

    public Page(int currentPage, IEnumerable<T> items, int itemsPerPage, int totalItems, int totalPages)
    {
        PageIndex = currentPage;
        _items = items.ToList();
        TotalItems = totalItems;
        PageSize = itemsPerPage;
        TotalPages = totalPages;
    }

    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int PageSize { get; private set; }
    public int TotalItems { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Then this is parsed into a Json in the Controller when returning the action response in order to match the json structure needed for the grid plugin (whereas it is jqGrid or DataTables).

I cannot change the Page structure and the pagination mechanics as it would hugely impact in the web application, so that's out of discussion. I need to find a way to adapt DataTables so it sends the *PageNumber* instead of the *Start* record. The *Length* parameter would match the *PageSize* on my side so it would fit perfectly.

Comment: How does your current code looks like? It is hard to answer without knowing what exactly behavior you want to accomplish.

Comment: It's not something about the visual aspect of the table, it's about how the plugin works behind scenes. Right now the DataTables plugin sends to the server the starting record of the page it wants to show and the amount of records to bring, then the server replies accordingly. I want DataTables to send the page number instead (along with the amount of records, which would remain similar to before).

Comment: Yes, so please add your code to the question. By code I mean how you want to access dataTables by pagenumber, i.e how you are doing it now with jqGrid.

Comment: I just edited my previous comment

Comment: dataTables sents displaystart and displayend to the server === a page . I have hoped you could provide how you expect this to work clientside so your code could be calibrated to your needs, but apparently you dont think this is nessecary to inform about. Good luck.  _To avoid confusion : dataTables is clientside, the serverside part is solely your job_.

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining well enough, so I'll try to rephrase: I'm implementing a basic snipet of datatables with the serverprocess option so the datatable makes the call to the server automatically. The code I'm using is just the very basic provided in datatables examples. Datatables, as you explained, sends (amongst other parameters) the parameters "start" and "length". My problem is that my server-side backend doesn't take "start" as the starting record from which to bring the rows, my backend takes "pageNumber". So basically, I would need a way to configure DT to, somehow, send this over.

Comment: Because of how my server-side backend is implemented I couldn't support both ways of sending paginated info tonthe client, so I was expecting to find a way to "tune" datatables for sending the page number I click on the pager instead of automatically calculate and send over the next starting record position for the page requested.

Comment: Yes, I have figured that out. As already written, you have to deal with your serverside script, or backend. An alternative is to rewrite dataTables to send those parameters you'll need. A third solution could be to create a "proxy" between dataTables as it is and your backend, unfortunately it is not possible since you wont tell how your backend works or how you have been targeting the backend clienside, so far, with jqGrid.

Comment: Hi @davidkonrad, thanks for your comments. I just added some more code to the question so you can take a look. Sorry for the delay, I had to be in my work computer to share it. Let me know if you need more info. The proxy idea might be a good one. Hope to see your explanation :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ajax.data`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) property to modify data submitted to the server.

```js
$('#example').dataTable( {
   "processing": true,
   "serverSide": true,
   "ajax": {
      "url": "script.php",
      "data": function(d, settings){
         var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);

         // Convert starting record into page number
         d.pageNumber = Math.min(
            Math.max(0, Math.round(d.start / api.page.len())),
            api.page.info().pages
         );
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: This is very similar to the temporary solution I came up with today. But I override the whole ajax call with my own, so yours is better. Could you make it so it only adds the pageNumber property to the data object instead of overwrite start? With this I will approve it. Also one question: I calculated the pageNumber with Math.floor(data.start / data.length), what difference would that make with your way? Thanks!

Comment: I added a new property `pageNumber` instead of modifying `start`. Regarding request data `length` property, I believe there could be cases where its value does not equal to actual page length, for example with [Scroller](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller) extension. But in your case, `d.start` and `api.page.len()` should be equal.

Comment: Would be better do this on the server rather on client. As you would anyway get start and limit in the params.

Comment: @PamioSolanky, I totally agree, but that was the requirement of the OP.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Yeah I understand and that was just a suggestion.

Comment: Perfect! I owe you 